# Wrapping the bootstrap drop-down menu and trigger in separate parent divs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

As title says, I've seen bootstrap dropdown samples which **`data-toggle="dropdown"`** and **`class="dropdown-menu"`** are siblings.

So, I am wondering if it's possible to toggle dropdown when it's wrapped in another div by using **`data-target`** or **`aria-labelledby`** attributes (without adding any js).

As like this example in [**`JSFIDDLE LINK`**](http://jsfiddle.net/aydVP/)

note: you will get the working example, if u remove '#LIST_WRAPPER'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it has nothing to do with data-target or aria. Its all simple css and jquery that makes the dropdown work in bootstrap. Two options we have if we want to separate them out:-

1. Javascript/Jquery way to manually toggle the menu on click (I learnt that you don't want to take that).
2. Css way.

All that bootstrap does is it toggles an `open` class to the parent of the trigger (You can see that if you look at the code).

#### Section from BS JS.

```
    $parent = getParent($this)
    isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')
    clearMenus()
    if (!isActive) {
        $parent.toggleClass('open')
    }
```

Once that is done CSS takes over, since naturally according to BS samples menu is inside the parent of the trigger itself so this style (immediate child selector) gets applied to it as `open` class is appended to it.

#### Section from BS CSS.

```
.open>.dropdown-menu {
   display: block; /*Makes the element visible*/
}
```

So based on your requirement we would need to override this to specify our own style.

```
.open .dropdown-menu {
       display: block; /*Makes the element visible*/
       top:auto; /*Rest the top, according to the current style top is positioned based on the parent but that doesn exist anymore, so need to reset it or play around with it*/
    }
```

All is well till here. Next issue is Font-Size not applied it  is zero. Ideal scenario it comes from the following rule from BS CSS for dropdown menu:-

```
.btn-group>.btn,
.btn-group>.dropdown-menu,
.btn-group>.popover
 {font-size:14px;}
```

This is obvious as the .dropdown-menu is a direct child of `.btn-group` based on your root container i.e `<div class="dropdown btn-group">`. SO 2 ways to fix it either remove  `btn-group` from the container div or set up a rule as follows:-

```
.btn-group .dropdown-menu {
    font-size:14px;
}
```

SO altogether 2 rules to be added:-

```
.open .dropdown-menu {
    display:block;
    top:auto;
}
.btn-group .dropdown-menu {
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Here is a **<kbd>[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gSQSw/)</kbd>**.

Comment: Seeing this solves my riddle, I realize i was being so stupid to search that far. Thanks :).

Comment: I was just madly curious with this since bootstrap dropdown toggle selector is '$this.attr('data-target') || $this.attr('href')'. I need to explore more. Cheers.

Comment: Yes it gets messed up when you specify them, it applies `open` on the `ul` and eventually doesn't work... Its all in the JS and looking at the code it doesn't seem like they wanted to support this kind of behavior.

Comment: +1 it always helps digging into the bootstrap core to understand